# Maintain border-spacing when using show() on a display:table element hidden with display:none

Tags: jquery, html, css

I have a `form` with a `select` element from which a user can select `value="Yes"` or `value="No"`.  If `value="Yes"`, JQuery uses `.show()` to show a `div` containing a `textarea` so that the user can explain the yes answer.  Otherwise, the `textarea` needs to be hidden.

The form is set up as a CSS `table`, with each line of the form being a `table-row` with one or more `table-cell`s.

I tried to have the `textarea` initially hidden with `display:none` in CSS because when I use JQuery to hide it, it flickers on the screen for a moment before JQuery gets around to hiding it.

However, initially hiding it with `display:none` results in another problem: when you subsequently show it using JQuery, it ignores the `10px` of spacing on the left and right sides.

[This fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/vincentpace/e10hmq2p/1/) is set up to hide it with the JQuery, and if you uncomment the last line of CSS you can see how the side spacing disappears after showing it with JQuery. (The flickering issue is not noticeable on the fiddle because I stripped out all other code.)  When uncommented, the two commented lines in the JQuery will make it work with `display:none`, but they do this by manipulating the CSS, meaning it will have to be manually changed if the spacing is ever changed.

Is there a way to maintain the `border-spacing` when using `show()`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I was writing up this question, I figured out what the issue was.  The element needed to be `display:table`. With the CSS initially set to `display:none`, `.show()` had no indication that it needed to be returned to `display:table` and instead was displaying it as `display:block`. This is why the `display:table` formatting `border-spacing` was not working: it doesn't work with `display:block`.

The easiest solution I came up with was not using `.show()` at all but instead creating a new `table_hidden` class with `display:none` and then using `.removeClass()` and `.addClass()` to effect the show/hide. [Here's a fiddle.](http://jsfiddle.net/vincentpace/jrfqw9v5/)